# How to trim stroke and fill in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: eye]

Hi there, I'm trying to figure out how to trim the overlapping fill and stroke on this picture of an eye. Is the knife tool the only option for this? I've been trying to figure this out for a while now with no luck.

Comment: So I want the blue of the iris that extends past the upper and lower eyelids to be removed. When I bring the blue in front the eyelids are masked but I don't understand where to go from there. I have tried making a clipping mask but this still does not give me the result I'm looking for.

Comment: Hi there, instead of adding a comment [edit your answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/88186/edit) to include any extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate the two eye strokes. Join them (command-J). Use that as a clipping mask or use it on "intersect" with the pathfinder on the eye circle.

Comment: that's a good solution that keeps your shapes intact, better than cutting most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

I quess that the top and bottom circle segments are exessive and must be removed.

For that divide your eye by 2 new shapes that cover the area to be removed.

Sorry for the crushed eye. It's only a screen capture + coarse vectorizing.

[image]

[image]

NOTE: You have the eyelid as paths, I have only blackish areas with fuzzy edges. Draw the dividing shapes exactly along the eyelids (=smart quides and snap to point on) then you get perfect results.

TOTAL OFFTOPIC:

The round shape is complete in a way. Consider to save it by having more curves.
(I have no way to make the old curves narrower)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'm new and really struggling with this. I still can't figure out how to divide the eye by two new shapes. When I use divide objects below the blue iris disappears. Is there a different tool that I should use to make the division? Thanks for your suggestion of having more curves I like that better

Comment: @Mace When choosing Divide Objects Below, the only selected part must be one of the new shapes. That shape mus be on the top. Object > Arrange > Bring to Front. The selected object divides all below.