# Just keep object + intersection

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I am new to Adobe Illustrator and I need to make a logo.

> How can I dynamically keep only the part of the earth which is inside
>   the white circle?

I tried with Pathfinder but **the result is fixed**. When it is done, I cannot change how much the earth enter inside the circle anymore.

I want it **dynamic**.

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trim stroke and fill in Illustrator](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/88186/how-to-trim-stroke-and-fill-in-illustrator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of your circle at the same place onto your earth.

Use the copy as a clipping mask for the Earth. (select both, goto Object > Clipping mask > Make)

If you want to re-edit, release the mask. The earth and the circle copy return to their original shapes except the circle copy has lost its stroke.

If you need the adjustability for the appearance negotiations, make a fake background with a hole - that is created easily by the pathfinder panel. Keep the earth behind it.